# Jax-rs alter serialization response based on request with jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

Currently facing an issue where I would like to alter the response of jax-rs resources based on some information passed into the response. The change that need to be made is the format of some of the json. Currently I am registering an ObjectMapper using jax @Provider and ContextResolver. However the getContext() method is only invoked a single time for each resource class. It is not possible to alter this based on every request.

Is it possible to inject or access the ObjectMapper in a ContainerResponseFilter?

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new DateDeserializer("some data format"));
        mapper.registerModule(module);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return getMapperBasedOnRequest();
    }

    private ObjectMapper getMapperBasedOnRequest() {
        if (true) {
            return mapper;
        } else {
            return //something else;
        }
    }

    private boolean containsLegacyHeader() {
        return //get some information from the request headers or body
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve this issue by using a Filter which would be invoked based on a parameter provided in the request, in this case a header.

```
public class DemoFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private final String UTC = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
    private final String OTHER = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    public static final String DATE_UTC = "utc";

    private String getMapperBasedOnRequest(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        if (checkHeader(requestContext)) {
            return OTHER;
        } else {
            return UTC;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkHeader(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        return //check header
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        ObjectWriterInjector.set(new DateMod(getMapperBasedOnRequest(requestContext)));

    }

    public static class DateMod extends ObjectWriterModifier {

        private String df;

        public DateMod(String df) {
            this.df = df;
        }


        @Override
        public ObjectWriter modify(EndpointConfigBase<?> endpointConfigBase, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> multivaluedMap, Object o, ObjectWriter objectWriter, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator) throws IOException {
            return objectWriter.with(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat));

        }
    }

}
```